# Why is the outside of my foreground black?

Tags: color, layers

I am currently following Cg geek's vfx tutorial. When I render the foreground, everything is black except my robot. I moved the ground to the background archive and i don't know why its showing in the foreground.

I added motion tracking and I am combining the 2 layers in the compositing window.You may have to render the 2 layers for them to appear in the compositing window.[image] I followed his steps, but i don't know why its black. If you could help me out, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

[image: vfx]

[image]

Comment: Did you enabe film-> Transparent?

Comment: No i did not, when I did. It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!